# Separating EF from the BLL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have the following piece of database transaction wrapper written :

```
 public class ExampleWrapper : IDisposable
    {
        public DbContextTransaction Transaction { get; set; }
        public DcatContext DatabaseContext { get; set; }

        public ExampleWrapper ()
        {
            DatabaseContext = new someContext();
            Transaction = DatabaseContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
          Transaction.Dispose();                      
        }


        public void Commit()
        {
           Transaction.Commit();

        }

        public void RollBack()
        {
            Transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
```

I have code something similar to the following  in my DAL  :

```
public async Task<Object> Retrieve(string Id)
        {

            using (var context= new  SomeContext())
            {
                return Context.Object.Find(id);
            }
        }
```

I am trying to keep the business layer separate from any Entity Framework dependency and that's the reason for the wrapper Class. If I am trying to do a transaction from the BLL for example:

```
using(var wrapper = new ExampleWrapper())
{
     //make calls to the DAL 
       something.Retrieve(Id)
}
```

My question is I am initializing the Dbcontext twice (Here while creating a transaction, as well as in the DAL) . Is there any suggestion any of you have how I can do this better? .

PS: Just using retrieve in a transaction as an example .

Comment: Sorry .. I assumed i just put enough to get the idea .

Comment: I suggest you look at this: https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope

Comment: In more current nomenclature, your `ExampleWrapper` is a *Unit of Work* and `Retrieve` should be in a *generic repository*. Now if you lookup this combination you'll find examples how to do this right.

Comment: You can use the repository pattern to separate the data access implementatio nfrom the business layer and use dependency injection to control the creation of the context, I have a full example in this URL https://github.com/haitham-shaddad/AppointmentManager and you can check my post about the steps here https://haithamshaddad.com/2016/03/15/building-a-lob-application-with-mvc-5-part-3-entityframework/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dependency Injection (e.g Ninject) to inject the DbContext to the 
Wrapper.  Then you can define the lifetime of the DBContext instances.  If it is a web application, then you can define the lifetime of the DbContext to be within the life of the Web Request (InRequestScope), so that it will automatically dispose of the DbContext after the Web Request ends.

You would no longer require creating the DbContext, since Ninject creates it for you and manages its disposal.